# Shifting column values in Pandas Dataframe causes missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift column values one space to the left. I don't want to save the original values of the column 'average_rating'.

[image]

I used the shift command:

```
data3 = data3.shift(-1, axis=1)
```

But the output I get has missing values for two columns- 'num_pages' and 'text_reviews_count'

[image]

Comment: You will get better help if you post better [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data frames to reproduce instead of posting images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the data types of the source and target columns do not match. Try converting the column value after `shift()` to the target data type for each source and target column - for example `.fillna(0).astype(int)`.

Alternately, you can convert all the data in the data frame to strings and then perform the shift. You might want to convert them back to their original data types again.

```
df = df.astype(str)  # convert all data to str
df_shifted = (df.shift(-1,axis=1))  # perform the shift
df_string = df_shifted.to_csv()  # store the shifted to a string variable
new_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_string), index_col=0)  # read the data again from the string variable
```

Output:

```
   average_rating        isbn  isbn13 language_code  num_pages  ratings_count  text_reviews_count  extra
0            3.57  0674842111  978067         en-US        236             55                 6.0    NaN
1            3.60  1593600119  978067           eng        400             25                 4.0    NaN
2            3.63  156384155X  978067           eng        342             38                 4.0    NaN
3            3.98  1857237250  978067           eng        383           2197                17.0    NaN
4            0.00  0851742718  978067           eng         49              0                 0.0    NaN
```